# Are questions about undocumented functions deprecated on Mathematica.SE

Tags: discussion

Feel little sorry for [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151017/whats-purpose-of-the-internaltoequivalenceclass).For refine my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149968/21532), I have done some dig about `ArrayComponents`.Then I found `` Internal`ToEquivalenceClass `` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9gAO.png) today. Actually I meet it many time before this in those defined page. Maybe it cannot help to improve my solution.I have to say,it is maybe a more *curious as [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) blamed* but not for some certain intention. I have recited almost all built-in function in *Mathematica*,I just want to find out some new thing to study.

And [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151017/whats-purpose-of-the-internaltoequivalenceclass#comment403163_151017) hint the `` Internal`* `` function is useless for user(maybe just usefull developer).But as we know,such as `` Internal`AbsSquare ``,`` Internal`StringToDouble ``,`` Internal`ListMin `` or `` Internal`Bag `` or other things have a good exposure rate in *MMA.SE*.I think the *SE* is a place to discuss openly.If someon else also are interested in those undocumented function like me. we can dig and discuss it together. If it wast somebody's time,it not my intention indeed..

Comment: **1._** I think there is plenty of precedent for discussing undocumented functions, I personally would welcome them in general terms.
**2._** That particular question, seems to lack any meaningful motivation and is very unlikely to attract interest, therefore it does need work.
**3._** In any case, however off-topic a question may be, it does not justify any kind of angry outburst, from anybody.

Comment: I think most undocumented functions are going to be uninteresting, unknowable outside WRI, not worth explaining, and primarily for supporting other user-level functions. The few exceptions may seem like a lot, but they form a small proportion of all such functions. Further, the exceptions have tended to appear in answers, not in out-of-the-blue questions. The insipidness of picking arbitrarily a function to ask about should be flavored with some context suggesting its potential importance as a standalone function (= point **2._** of rhermans's comment & the 2nd para. of m_goldberg's answer).

Comment: One of my favorite used to be ``BoxForm`Intercalate``. It has the same basic usage as `Riffle`.

Comment: @ChrisChiasson that was not an answer, consider: [805](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/5478)

Comment: @Kuba please explain why, in detail

Comment: @ChrisChiasson the question is: "Are questions about undocumented functions deprecated on Mathematica.SE?" better tell me how your example answers that. Isn't it exactly what is considered an answer in linked topic?

Comment: @Kuba what you put in direct quotation marks does not appear in yode's question, unless I am missing something. I read his question as: assuming it is within the rules for him to ask, what undocumented functions do we know about that we can share with him. Please show cause as to why my answer isn't an answer.

Comment: @ChrisChiasson the only question I see appears in a title, maybe should be repeated in the body I agree, nevertheless it is that vs your interpretation of the topic. Either is fine for  me but yours and m_goldberg's answers answer different asspects and it can't be that both are the case. Since he was first and OP already responded, not claiming it is off topic answer, I suppose it is clear

Comment: @ChrisChiasson OP's invitation to dig and discuss seem (to me) to be an additional invitation for creating a chat/discussion group rather than a direct purpose of the question. Again, I may be wrong but the topic should be clear so we can wait for yode to clarify.

Comment: @Kuba, I think you were too quick with your moderation, regardless of the ultimate resolution

Comment: @ChrisChiasson Your answer was flagged as 'not an answer' by community members so it was not only mine impression. I will gladly revert my actions it they were too quick but the case is 'explicit question in the title' vs your interpretation. And yours answer validity makes the existing answer off topic. So I did what I did because it was a matter of facts not interpretation. Sorry if you felt I could have been more subtle, I will take that lesson.

Comment: @Kuba,Chris Chiasson I'm not a new user in *SE*.Actually I always confused why some question posted by me always unhappy for some people.Such as the recent two posts([one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151017/whats-purpose-of-the-internaltoequivalenceclass),[two](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151458/why-the-export-the-graphics-or-image-to-local-file)).Those is closed now,but I think they are useful post still.Since that post is closed now tagged with *question is out of scope*.It is relevant to the subject(undocument function).

Comment: @Kuba, I think it should be reverted, if only because yode has yet to mark anything as an accepted answer. Turning my answer into a comment denies yode the opportunity to decide if my answer is acceptable. Lastly, I'd note that like yode, I'm hardly a new user or spam bot.

Comment: @yode, in the words of my generation: haters gonna hate ( http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Haters%20Gonna%20Hate )

Comment: @ChrisChiasson Do you feel that I treated you like I would a spam bot? Also I don't agree, it exists as a comment and yode can reply to you. Accepting an answer is meant to pick the best answer, not to mark valid answers.

Comment: @ChrisChiasson Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba Take It easy.Not all action can meet anyone.You are a good moderation.

Comment: I agree with @Kuba it's not an answer. It's not even about the ***website***, which is the overall subject of Meta.

Comment: The question is clearly about the validity of discussing undocumented functions and not about generating a gallery of favorite undocumented functions. @yode wrote "I think the SE is a place to discuss openly. If someone else also are interested in those undocumented function like me, we can dig and discuss it together" and I agree with him, that should be allowed in general terms. A different point is if particular instances of such questions are well explained and likely to be of use for the site. There,I have to say that some questions are hard to understand or pose almost imposible tasks.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think questions about undocumented functions should be deprecated categorically. Like any other questions, the quality of such questions should be judged and those found wanting rejected. In the case of the question being condsidered here, I don't think the quality of the question was very high.

Had you discussed in your question how you came across  `` Internal`ToEquivalenceClass `` and how it relates to graph theory work, I would not have had such a hissy-fit. Had you asked the question well and, further, given a self-answer, I would have up-voted both the question and the answer.

Even now, I think it would have been better to bring the matter up in chat than to ask about it on main site.

Comment: I hope I have not offensed to you still. I just want to know how to ask a qualified question since you always think they're not very appropriate.

Comment: @yode. Not offense taken. I have a fairly thick skin. I have revised my answer to give my opinion how to make such questions acceptable. Further, I do ***not*** always disapprove of your questions. I have up-voted quite a few of them.

Comment: Anyway,thanks..:)